# Continuous functions on $(0,1)$ that have no fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-points

I need an example of a continuous function that does not have a fixed point, a function $f:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ with domain $(0,1)$ and image $(0,1)$.
Thanks.

Comment: y=x^2 is such an example.

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(x)=x^2
$$
Also, $f(x)=x^a$, for every $a\ne 1$, $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Any continous function will do as long as its graph does not intersect the diagonal line $y=x$. So for example the function $$x\mapsto \frac x2$$ will work, since $   \frac x2<x$ in the region of interest.  Similarly $$x\mapsto\frac {x+1}2$$ or $$ x\mapsto \min\bigg(\frac x3, \frac14\bigg)$$ or what have you.